# Creating a data set from the report's already-filtered data?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

My main report already has a complex filter, and rather than try and build it again with subqueries for my new data set, I'd like to simply query *from* the filtered result set itself. That is, can I specify that a data set use the data of the main report?

I'm using a data set to populate a pie graph, and I was wondering if this was possible.

Comment: I don't know if JasperReports can be pipelined like that. What I do in such situations is create a temporary table that contains the results and query it. Not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible, but if you restructure your data into a better reporting format, you probably don't need to do this.